# Jquery to analyze string values in ul list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

How do I compare the string in this list to verify that 'Suspension' exists in this list, but it is not part of the 'On-campus Suspension'? If indexof the word 'suspension' can work, how do I accomplish that?

```
<ul id='act_ul_0'>
  <li id="act_l1_0">
    <div class="itemlabel">
      Suspension
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="itemlabel">
  <ul id='act_ul_1'>
    <li id="act_l1_0">
      On-Campus Suspension
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See JavaScript's [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). You might also find jQuery's [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) useful.

Comment: @showdev thank you! this is really helpful. I am looping through the list, if indexof value is >0 it is on-campus, when 0: it is suspension.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Load the list items into an jQuery object / array
var $items = $('#act_ul_0').find('li');
// Define the string that you intend to match
var searchItem = "Suspension";
// Use the [jQuery.inArray()][1] function to search for your match
if ($.inArray(searchItem, $items) > -1) {
    // Pretty self-explanatory from here on, right?
    console.log("I found it!");
} else {
    console.log("No bueno!");
}
```

Comment: SO police.. HELP!

Comment: That police brutality tho! =P --- PS: Problem is no more. Obsolete noise removed. +1 added.